# IE6 double padding bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have created some colored boxes that display fine in other browsers, however IE6 is not displaying them properly. Before anyone asks or is sarcastic about why I am bothering to support IE6, it is not my decision, it is my managers.

The intention is that each colored box forms a square that is 220 pixels by 220 pixels as you can see in the jsFiddle below. The properties `height:100px;` and `padding: 20px 0 100px 20px;` in the class `.awards_square_enter` give the box a height of 220px.

I have also added some padding to to the `<span class="enter">` nested inside `.awards_square_enter` which is `padding: 45px 0 0 30px;` This padding seems to have doubled in IE6 and increased the height of the box beyond 220px .

http://jsfiddle.net/kFRrM/

```
.awards_square_enter a {
    background-image: url("../images/icons/right_arrow.png");  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 11% 85%; 
    display:block; 
    font-size: 30px;
    height:100px; 
    line-height: 1.1em;
    height:100px;  
    padding: 20px 0 100px 20px;
}
```

Here is how it appears in IE6 extending beyond the height of 220px:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any of the traditional methods of getting rid of the double padding bug?  http://breakthroughdesign.com/css-ie-double-padding-bug/851.  It should also be noted that older IE versions have an incorrect implementation of the box model (acts similar to `box-sizing: border-box`).

Answer (score 0):

so apply separate styles for ie6 via conditional comments. change the padding  you have set for both, until they equal what you desire, in the styles that are only going to ie6